# React Native - Recurrence rule UI for custom calendar

Tags: react-native, calendar

I'm trying to build a custom calendar that supports creating recurrent events. I need help with 2 things.

1. How to parse a recurrence rule and display UI
2. Generate a recurrence rule from the UI.

The web version of the mobile app is using Sync Fusion calendar which does the heavy lifting but unfortunately, there is no support for react native.

I tried searching for a library that generates UI from the recurrence rule and the recurrence rule itself from the UI(based on user actions). For the recurrence rule, I came across this JS library https://www.npmjs.com/package/rrule but I don't know how to achieve the above 2 using this.

Attached are the screens for defining recurrence.
[image]
[image]

Comment: @famfamfam We used the rrule js library to create a custom component for recurrence events

Comment: were you able to achieve this?